# npm ERR! could not detect node name from path or package

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

today i was trying to install my package in visual studio. But there is an error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTTFj.png)

npm i
npm ERR! could not detect node name from path or package

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\holan\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2021-09-01T00_08_12_922Z-debug.log

I reinstall node.js and python

here is my path
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyh0n.png)

sorry for my bad english but i need help

Comment: In order for someone to help you, they need to try to reproduce the error.
Could you please provide the whole command you typed when you got the error?
Also, if you can put a sample project on github so people can clone and try to help you it would make everyone's work easier.

Comment: You need to add the package name after `npm i`

Comment: It's likely one of two problems: 1) as Nat said: If you want to install an npm package globally ... *YOU SHOULD SPECIFY THE PACKAGE NAME*.  Otherwise, 2) If you've created a node-based project (e.g. an AngularJS project), then you can globally install the packages listed in your project's "package.json" file.  For this to work, *YOU MUST 'CD' INTO YOUR PROJECT'S ROOT FOLDER*.  'Hope that helps...

Answer (score 2):

As OP didn't provide details of the issue and seems to be new to nodejs, hereby explaining how `npm i` work in general matter.

There are main usage of `npm i`:

1. To install a package that haven't install in this project(or global) before, you can put that package name after the `npm i` , such as `npm i express`. Once the installation is done, it will insert the package name into `package.json` and the package source code in `node_modules`. You can think `package.json` is like a index and `node_modules` is the actual packages source code.
2. To install a package that listed in `package.json`. If you are copying/clone the project from other source , usually it has `package.json` but not the `node_modules`. In that case, you can use `npm i` to install all the packages that listed in `package.json` and it will then create the `node_modules`.

Using `npm i` without package.json will not install anything as there isn't a package name in the `npm i [package name]` and `package.json` .